# Adjusting Xscale & Yscale

Tags: data-visualization, stata

I am trying to edit the scale for both my x and y axes. The code below works for the yscale only:

```
twoway connected cum_area2 av_area if iso_code=="EGY",  lcolor (green) mcolor(green)  msize(small) msymbol(sh) yscale(range(0 8) axis(1))  ylabel(2 4 6 8, axis(1))  xtitle(Holding size (Ha))  ytitle(Cumulative area (mn Ha)) yline(4.09) legend(label(1 "Egypt"))
```

And the graph looks as follows:
[image]

However, I am also trying to edit the scale for the x axis and I tried the following code:

```
twoway connected cum_area2 av_area if iso_code=="EGY",  lcolor (green) mcolor(green)  msize(small) msymbol(sh) xscale(range(0 2000) axis(2)) xlabel(500 1000 1500 2000, axis(2)) yscale(range(0 8) axis(1))  ylabel(2 4 6 8, axis(1))   xtitle(Holding size (Ha))  ytitle(Cumulative area (mn Ha)) yline(4.09) legend(label(1 "Egypt"))
```

But I keep getting the following error: "xscale(range(0 2000) axis(2)) not allowed, xaxis2 does not exist"

Comment: I don't think you need the axis() suboption. What happens if you try without?

Comment: Thanks, I tried without that, and I get an error that parentheses do not  balance.

Comment: You need to specify `xaxis(1 2)` I think. Incidentally, ha not Ha is the standard abbreviation for hectare.